# Цюкати - розмовне чи загальновживане?

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова

В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/cjukaty) знаходимо слово **цюкати** без позначки **розм.**. Однак, в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) коло цього слова знаходжу позначку **розм.**. То як бути із слововживанням? Адже, позначка **розм.** його обмежує.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Словнику синонімів української мови. 2014](http://synonyms_uk.enacademic.com/6899/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) теж подають без позначок:

> сапати (знищувати бур'ян і підпушувати ґрунт сапою), сапувати, просапувати, просапати; шарувати; прошаровувати, прошарувати (між рядками посіву); **цюкати** (перев. не на повну силу); підсапувати, підсапати (зрубувати бур'ян навколо рослини).

Також і в наведеному Вами [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/cjukaty) без позначки. Це означає, що **слово загальновживане**, **літературне**, не діалектизм, не розмовне тощо.